# Nested IF Else in R - SAT/ACT test

Tags: r, nested

I have the following data set

```
df <- data.frame(student=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), sat=c(365,0,545,630,385,410,0,655,0), act=c(28,20,0,0,16,17,35,29,21))

student     sat    act
    1       365    28
    2         0    20
    3       545     0
    4       630     0
    5       385    16
    6       410    17
    7         0    35
    8       655    29
    9         0    21
```

and I'd like to create a new field with the following conditions

If there is an SAT score > 0 use SAT score
If SAT=0, then convert the ACT to an SAT score using the rubric [here](https://www.tntech.edu/admissions/actsat). (When there was a range in the SAT score, I just used the median.

```
ACT SAT
8   200
9   210
10  220
11  225
12  250
13  285
14  325
15  360
16  385
17  410
18  440
19  465
20  485
21  505
22  525
23  545
24  560
25  575
26  595
27  615
28  635
29  655
30  675
31  700
32  725
33  750
34  775
35  790
36  800
```

This is one heck of an ifelse statement. I've tried this:

```
df$newgrade=-ifelse(ACT=8,200, ifelse (ACT=9,210, ifelse(ACT=10,220, ifelse (ACT=11,225, ACT=12,250, ifelse(ACT=13,285, ifelse (ACT=14,325, ACT=15,D, ifelse(ACT=16,C, ifelse (ACT=17,B, ACT=18,D, ifelse(ACT=19,C, ifelse (ACT=20,B, ACT=21,D, ifelse(ACT=22,C, ifelse (ACT=23,B, ACT=24,D, ifelse(ACT=25,C, ifelse (ACT=26,B, ACT=27,D, ifelse(ACT=28,C, ifelse (ACT=29,B, ACT=30,D, ifelse(ACT=31,C, ifelse (ACT=32,B, ACT=33,D, ifelse(ACT=34,C, ifelse (ACT=35,B, ACT=36,D))))))))))))))))))))
```

I tried to follow the example at the bottom of this page but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how best to achieve this new field?

Thank you for any assistance you may bring.

Comment: What is the second data frame?, the conversion table? Assuming that the second table is the `conversion` `data.frame`, you can try:  `df$newgrade<-ifelse(df$sat == 0, conversion$SAT[match(df$act, conversion$ACT)], df$sat)`

Comment: there isn't one but i can easily turn that SAT/ACT conversion table into one. let's call it convert? would that help? where would i place it?

Comment: or is your second table listed here conversion? sorry I had to reread that

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much! can you mark it as the answer??

Comment: @SRivero A new issue came up and I was wondering if you could help me. If there is neither an ACT nor a SAT score. How can it put a 0 in for that group??
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What do you mean with that? the act value in not in the conversion table?Please explain

Comment: @SRivero  If there is an SAT score > 0 use SAT score If SAT=0, then convert the ACT to an SAT score using the rubric in conversion table  
Additionally:  If there is SAT=0 AND ACT=0 can the new grade then be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call `conversion` to the table you want to use to convert values when `df$sat==0`. Yo can do something like this:

`df$newgrade<-ifelse(df$sat == 0, conversion$SAT[match(df$act, conversion$ACT)], df$sat)`

EDIT: If you want to include another condition `df$sat ==0` and `df$act==0`, then `df$new grade==0`, you can include another ifelse:

`df$newgrade<-ifelse(df$sat == 0 & df$act == 0, 0, ifelse(df$sat == 0, conversion$SAT[match(df$act, conversion$ACT)], df$sat))`

or use `df[is.na(df)]<-0` after create the column `df$newgrade`, because in those cases ( `df$sat ==0` and `df$act==0` ) you'll have NAs